# Java stream map()'s variable can not resolved to a Type

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a problem with the Stream API. The variable in mapper always cannot be resolved.

My codes as below:

```
List<Object[]> splitUpNames = 
    Arrays.asList("John Woo", "Jeff Dean", "Josh Bloch", "Josh Long")
          .stream()
          .map(name -> name.split("")) // **here says  "name cannot be resolved to a variable"**
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have checked that the `stream()` method returns type of `Stream<String>`,  and I cannot figure out why the variable `name` can not be resolved to type `String`.

Comment: My compiler has no problems with this code.

Comment: Just for the record: you are sure that your IDE/compiler/setup is actually on Java8?

Comment: I just tried your code out and I do not get any error. You must have something else that causes the error.

Comment: @GhostCat If it wasn't Java 8 then it would complain that the `stream()` method didn't exist

Comment: @SamTebbs33 Maybe the IDE project is pointing to a JDK8; so the method will be found; but the IDE editor can still be backlevel; and not accepting java8 syntax. All I am saying is: this looks like a weird problem; definitely the code itself is correct; so it must be something else. So the thing you have to do is check the build/project setup.

Comment: @GhostCat  &  SamTebbs33 both right. I created my maven project in a poor way, the default version is 1.5, but I manually added java 8   lib as the JRE System lib (that's why compiler doesn't complain stream() ).  I have followed GhostCat's advice to change the compiler version, but the highest version is 1.7 ,Now I'm downloading java8 support from elclipse market, hopefully , should solve it. Tks a lot you guys

Comment: Downloading Java 8 support from Eclipse Market Place sounds like you are using a really old version of Eclipse. Since Luna (4.4, released June 2014) Eclipse supports Java 8 out of the box. Please consider using a recent version of Eclipse. Note that even JLS has changed after 2014.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann yes,  I tried mars and neon, just not running smoothly on my pc . now using kepler sr2 for learning which is ok

Comment: `String::split(String)` returns `String[]` so `splitUpNames`should have `List<String[]>` type, no?